# Dealing with duplication in RavenDB

Tags: nosql, ravendb

Taking my first shot at NoSQL development using RavenDB.

One thing that is confusing me is how we should handle duplicates across documents that are stored.

Let's say I have a Story (think BDD/ATDD):

```
{ 
    Id: 10,
    Title: 'Story 1'
}
```

Then I decide that a story can have one or more sub-stories. I then create another story and make then above story a sub-story.

```
{
    Id: 15,
    Title: 'Title',
    Stories: [ { Id: 10, Title: 'Story 1' }]
}
```

Now I've got two stories. If I load the story with ID=15 and proceed to edit the first story in the Stories array, let's say, with a new title of 'Sub-story 1', the original story stays the same.

What I'm trying to understand: Do I care? If I do, what is the best way to make sure that everything stays in sync? When the sub-story is changed, I want the original story to change as well. What is the appropriate design/solution for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you shouldn't model things like that.
See: http://ayende.com/blog/156353/entities-associations-point-in-time-vs-current-associations

Comment: I'm not entirely clear. How would you recommend I model the above if I want the data to change over time? Should I forget about having sub-stories? How should the parent story reference children?